# Add keys and values from a text file to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file `test.txt` with two lines on it:

```
1 "test one"
2 "test two"
```

I just want to add those 2 lines to `test_dict`:

```py
test_dict = {} 
with open("test.txt", "r") as f: 
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        test_dict[int(key)] = val

print(test_dict)
```

Error:

```py
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Expected result:

```py
test_dict = {1: "test one", 2: "test two"}
```

Comment: I think it doesn't have any problem, unless your txt file doesn't look like this exactly.

Comment: It is exactly as it is.

Comment: Does your second words have space in between? I mean (test_one and test_two)

Comment: In between 1 and test_one is a space.

Comment: Then I don't have any idea, it's just 3 lines of code, `split()` splits the lines from spaces, so there should be only 2 items in the returned list and you have exactly two variables to unpack them.

Comment: I have edited the lines  its now  1 "test one"
2 "test two"

Answer (score 0):

After you edited your question, this should work :

```
test_dict = {}
with open("testtt.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split(maxsplit=1)
        test_dict[int(key)] = val

print(test_dict)
```

Because we need the first item as a key, and "rest of them" as value, so I pass `maxsplit=1` as an argument to `split()`. This only split the line only 1 time from the left.

Comment: (key, val) = line.split(maxsplit=1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: Same error but you have given me idea on that maxsplit.

Comment: @GlennFord good, Make sure you are reading the correct file. sometimes happens... but this should work for you.

Comment: I'm reading the correct file. Thanks for advice.